# MySql Database In WordPress Multisite

Tags: multisite, database, mysql

I have a multi-site installation. It's a fresh installation, and currently all the sites use the same database. What would you recommend among these and why? Pros and Cons of using the same?

**Option 1 -** Same database for all WP Sites

**Option 2 -** A different database for every WP Site

Thanks.

Comment: What specific problem do you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be new with WP Multisite. That is OK. I'm using Multisite for last few years and I really don't know any way to put the different site tables in different database.

The way WP Multisite works is a single WP installation for multiple WP site. Now suppose you have a database called `my_multisite`; within this database WordPress will create all the tables. Now if it is a Multisite installation and at the time of installation if you select the table prefix (say `ex_`) then your root site tables will be like `ex_options` `ex_blah_blah`. Now when you will create another site within that Multisite installation, the prefix value will be incremented by 1 and the new sites will have the same tables with the names like `ex_2_options` `ex_2_blah_blah`. For next site you create it will be `ex_3_options` `ex_3_blah_blah`, `...`. There is no way change this pattern.

Trust me this is all right for your site. If you want to have your different site tables to different database, you have to go with multiple WordPress single installations. But Multisite database does not degrade any performance for most of the good hosts. Just make sure you host your site with a legit and good hosting company.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I would still want someone to explain the pros and cons of using a diff db for diff sites on the multi-site installation.

Comment: You cant use different DB for different site in a multisite environment. So there is no pros and cons. Read my answer properly.